# Know proportions of ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I usually save the plots from `ggplot2` using the the `png` device. The width and the height of the output are set by the arguments of the function. Blank zones are drawn when the "natural proportions" of the graph dont't suit the proportions of the device. In order to avoid this and use the whole defined canvas, the proportions of the plot must be known. ¿Is there a way to find out this value without trial and error?

This code can be  used as an example:

```
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1)
y <- seq(from = 1, to = 2, by = 0.1)
df <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
df <- cbind(df, z = rnorm(ncol(df), 0, 1))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() + coord_fixed()

ppi <- 300

#Value 0.4 is used to change inches into milimeters
png("plot.png", width = 16*0.4*ppi, height = 20*0.4*ppi, res = ppi)
print(p)
dev.off()
```

It can be seen that some blank space is added at the top and at the bottom to fill the png file. This could be easily corrected by using a proportion different from 20/16, which is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `ratio` arg inside `coord_fixed()`:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill = z)) + 
       geom_raster() + 
       coord_fixed(ratio = 20/16)
```

Alteratively you can specify the `aspect.ratio` inside the `theme()`:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill = z)) + 
       geom_raster() + 
       theme(aspect.ratio = 20/16)
```

The result is the same:

[image]

Comment: I mean that the "natural proportions" when the coordinates ratio is fixed should take into account the size of the titles, the legend, the strip of the facets, etc. If a ratio of 1 is fixed in ´coord_fixed´ in this plot, and a ratio of 1 is also fixed in the proportion of ´width´ and ´height´, there will be a blank zone in the png file due to the axis labels, legend, etc.